# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with characterAtIndex, but not substringToIndex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to Objective-C and as a very simple learning exercise, I have created a method to return the first initial of a variable storing a name:

```
-(NSString *)initial
{
    return [_name substringToIndex:1];
}
```

This works exactly as intended when I use substringToIndex, however if I instead use characterAtIndex I receive a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Can anyone explain why one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: show how _name is being declared and set in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

characterAtIndex returns a char, not a (NSString *), probably the problem is in returning the wrong type.

Comment: This answer solves the problem and I hate to nitpick, but `characterAtIndex:` does not return `char` it returns a `unichar` which is a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

Like yoprogramo stated, a character is not an NSString. Since your method is returning a pointer to a string, the char you're returning is being read as a pointer. When your program goes to read from that memory address, it's throwing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.